# Getting the message "Message delivery status ERROR_DELIVERING", is there a way to automatically resend the sms?

Tags: clickatell

I have clickatell connected to my marketing platform, and I'm sending a general message. My question is, when I get the message "Message delivery status ERROR_DELIVERING" (in clickatell), is there a way in clickatell, to resend it automatically?